# How can I access Microsoft Dynamics CRM from android device?

Tags: android, dynamics-crm-4

I would like to know if Android OS is compatible with Dynamics CRM 4 Mobile Express.

When I open the CRM web page `https://server/m`, I receive a white screen. The same request works on an iPhone and Blackberry.

I already disabled the Popup-Blocker and enabled JavaScript.

Comment: As this question is out of the scope of this site (See the [faq] for clarification), I would kindly invite you to support the [Microsoft Dynamics proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/32455/microsoft-dynamics?referrer=jHf4j_VcIgLKPEy52a9q2g2) if you are generally interested in this topic

Answer (score 0):

IMHO there is no dedicated requirements overview for Dynamics CRM 4, but as the mobile interface has not really changed I would say that the requirements for Dynamics CRM 2011 are the same as for Dynamics CRM 4: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367440.aspx

> Mobile Express will only run on a mobile device that has a web browser that supports HTML 4.0 or a later version and JavaScript.

As it works on your other devices it could be some network related error.

Comment: i mean, how can find a mobile browser which support html 4.0 on android ? is it possible.Also there is a app on android market thats called "Mobile Client for Microsoft Dynamics CRM" http://www.bfi-mobile.com/ its says android support.Is it works ?

Comment: The default browser is capable to open the page. Just tested it. If it doesn't work for you, your problem is something else. The client which you have found is third-party and needs a server side component.